# send and recv on same socket from different threads not working

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, send, recv

I read that it should be safe from different threads concurrently, but my program has some weird behaviour and I don't know what's wrong.

I have concurrent threads communicating with a client socket

1. one doing send to a socket
2. one doing select and then recv from the same socket

As I'm still sending, the client has already received the data and closed the socket.
At the same time, I'm doing a select and recv on that socket, which returns 0 (since it is closed) so I close this socket. However, the send has not returned yet...and since I call close on this socket the send call fails with EBADF.

I know the client has received the data correctly since I output it after I close the socket and it is right. However, on my end, my send call is still returning an error (EBADF), so I want to fix it so it doesn't fail.

This doesn't always happen. It happens maybe 40% of the time. I don't use sleep anywhere. Am I supposed to have pauses between sends or recvs or anything?

Here's some code:

Sending:

```
while(true)
{
    // keep sending until send returns 0
    n = send(_sfd, bytesPtr, sentSize, 0);

    if (n == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else if(n<0)
    {
        cerr << "ERROR: send returned an error "<<errno<< endl; // this case is triggered
        return n;
    }

    sentSize -= n;
    bytesPtr += n;
}
```

Receiving:

```
 while(true)
{
    memset(bufferPointer,0,sizeLeft);
    n = recv(_sfd,bufferPointer,sizeLeft, 0);
    if (debug) cerr << "Receiving..."<<sizeLeft<<endl;
    if(n == 0)
    {
        cerr << "Connection closed"<<endl; // this case is triggered
        return n;
    }
    else if (n < 0)
    {
        cerr << "ERROR reading from socket"<<endl;
        return n;
    }
     bufferPointer += n;
     sizeLeft -= n;
     if(sizeLeft <= 0) break;

}
```

On the client, I use the same receive code, then I call close() on the socket.
Then on my side, I get 0 from the receive call and also call close() on the socket
Then my send fails. It still hasn't finished?! But my client already got the data!

Comment: Please add some code. There may be errors extraneous to what you suspect.

Comment: Could always give the socket a reference count.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious What do you mean? How does keeping a reference prevent the error? I thought simultaneous send and recvs are ok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem. It's with my loop. Notice that it's an infinite loop. When I don't have anymore left to send, my sentSize is 0, but I'll still loop to try to send more. At this time, the other thread has already closed this thread and so my send call for 0 bytes returns with an error.

I fixed it by changing the loop to stop looping when sentSize is 0 and it fixed the problem!

Comment: Heh, I just spotted that now myself. That'll teach me to answer questions late at night before bed! The issues I talk about in my answer are still valid, but as I said you wouldn't expect to see them that often.

Answer (score 5):

I must admit I'm surprised you see this problem as often as you do, but it's always a possibility when you're dealing with threads. When you call `send()` you'll end up going into the kernel to append the data to the socket buffer in there, and it's therefore quite likely that there'll be a context switch, maybe to another process in the system. Meanwhile the kernel has probably buffered and transmitted the packet quite quickly. I'm guessing you're testing on a local network, so the other end receives the data and closes the connection and sends the appropriate FIN back to your end very quickly. This could all happen while the sending machine is still running other threads or processes because the latency on a local ethernet network is so low.

Now the FIN arrives - your receive thread hasn't done a lot lately since it's been waiting for input. Many scheduling systems will therefore raise its priority quite a bit and there's a good chance it'll be run next (you don't specify which OS you're using but this is likely to happen on at least Linux, for example). This thread closes the socket due to its zero read. At some point shortly after this the sending thread will be re-awoken, but presumably the kernel notices that the socket is closed before it returns from the blocked `send()` and returns `EBADF`.

Now this is just speculation as to the exact cause - among other things it heavily depends on your platform. But you can see how this could happen.

The easiest solution is probably to use `poll()` in the sending thread as well, but wait for the socket to become write-ready instead of read-ready. Obviously you also need to wait until there's any buffered data to send - how you do that depends on which thread buffers the data. The `poll()` call will let you detect when the connection has been closed by flagging it with `POLLHUP`, which you can detect before you try your `send()`.

As a general rule you shouldn't close a socket until you're certain that the send buffer has been fully flushed - you can only be sure of this once the `send()` call has returned and indicates that all the remaining data has gone out. I've handled this in the past by checking the send buffer when I get a zero read and if it's not empty I set a "closing" flag. In your case the sending thread would then use this as a hint to do the close once everything is flushed. This matters because if the remote end does a half-close with `shutdown()` then you'll get a zero read even if it might still be reading. You might not care about half closes, however, in which case your strategy above is OK.

Finally, I personally would avoid the hassle of sending and receiving threads and just have a single thread which does both - that's more or less the point of `select()` and `poll()`, to allow a single thread of execution to deal with one or more filehandles without worrying about performing an operation which blocks and starves the other connections.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem you described seems very possible, but I don't think I am experiencing it because it seems to require a very specific situation, and the error I get happens very very often. Also, I need to use multiple threads because it was an assignment specification for school. The closing flag comment sounds very useful and I would add that if it were for a job, but this is just for marks haha.

Comment: @cartroo - How can you recv and send on the same socket and the same thread when recv is a blocking call? poll() and select() sound like they are meant entirely for use with multiple sockets.

Comment: @JoeManiaci Both `send()` and `recv()` aren't necessarily blocking operations. Firstly, they only block if they're unable to make any progress, otherwise they return a partial success - the point of `select()` and `poll()` is to detect when such a sucess is possible (i.e. they won't block). Secondly, you can make a socket non-blocking with the `O_NONBLOCK` option. Thirdly, `select()` and `poll()` work fine with a single socket - they let you wait for multiple events on as many descriptors as you have, even one. They're designed to scale to many, but that doesn't stop you using them with one.

Comment: But just to clarify, if you're using `select()` or `poll()` then in principle you shouldn't need `O_NONBLOCK`. Provided you're careful, those calls will guarantee to you that you can make a single call to either `send()` or `recv()` as appropriate to the event you get and it won't block. Most people still use `O_NONBLOCK` in case they make a slight mistake somewhere, or for the efficiency of being able to loop over `send()` / `recv()` to pull out all the data in one go even with a fixed buffer size. But that's the implementer's choice.